# android live wallpaper display image in drawable directory

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I need to create a live wallpaper where it just pulls an image from the drawable directory.
Is there an example somewhere that I can refer to?

It would be nice if the example also shows how to draw something simple on top of the image as well. If not, its ok =)

the one on the Android.com site just has drawing a cube =(

thanks for any comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy))). Use something like this.

In your `Engine` constructor use something like this

```
Bitmap _background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
```

and in your code use this

```
private final int WEATHER_ANIMATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private final Handler _handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable weatherAnimation = new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        drawNextFrame();
    }
};

private void drawNextFrame()
{

final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

try {
    _canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (_canvas != null)
            {
                drawAnimation(_canvas);
            }
    }
    finally
            {
            if (_canvas != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(_canvas);
        }
        // schedule the next frame
        _handler.removeCallbacks(weatherAnimation);
        if (_visible)
        {
            _handler.postDelayed(weatherAnimation, WEATHER_ANIMATION_INTERVAL);
        }
        return;
}
private void drawAnimation(Canvas c) 
    {
        c.drawBitmap(_background, _xOffset, _yOffset, _paint);
        _weather.draw(c, _xOffset, _yOffset, _paint);
    }
```

I hope this help you

Comment: I have another question...I have a very wide picture, how come it only shows the part that fits on "current" screen. I see other live wallpaper where the picture scrolls as you move to a different workspace left or right...is that an easy option? Thanks

Comment: public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) 
        {
         _xOffset = xPixels;
         _yOffset = yPixels;
        }